# Java, REST-application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rest

Делаю пример REST приложения [из официального сайта Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/). GET,DELETE запросы работают нормально, при POST возникает ошибка:

```
{"timestamp":1571228960142,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/employees"} rl: (6) Could not resolve host: Samwise Gamgee,curl: (6) Could not resolve host: rolecurl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9
```

Погуглил, нашел ответы что это [проблемы с десереализацией объектов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488861/how-to-fix-415-unsupported-media-type-for-rest-api-between-angular-7-and-java), добавив недостающие элементы и подключив Core Jackson ошибка осталась.

Мой котроллер:

```
package com.exampleREST.RESTAPPL;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeRepository repository;

    EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // Aggregate root

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    List<Employee> all() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/employees",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
        return repository.save(newEmployee);
    }

    // Single item

    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(employee -> {
                    employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
                    employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
                    return repository.save(employee);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newEmployee.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newEmployee);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.exampleREST</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTAPPL</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTAPPL</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <jackson.version>2.3.1.GA</jackson.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: [Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody MultiValueMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33796218/312041) ?

Comment: при внесении изменений из ответа выше, возникает новая ошибка: Запрос: curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
Ответ:

{"id":3,"name":null,"role":null}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Samwise Gamgee,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: role
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9

Comment: это уже совершенно другая проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тестов лучше используйте программы типа  Postman. Если отправлять запросы через консоль, почему-то теряется 'Content-type:application/json'.